# How to maintain DRY rule in 3 layers app with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've created WPF app with 3 layers: DataAccess, DomainLogic and Views.
DataAccess contains IRepository and Repository with Add, Edit, Remove GetOne and GetAll methods based on MSSQL database and some ModelData from DomainLogic layer.
DomainLogic contains some additional logic for GetAll method, so it contains IService interface and Service class. In Service class constructor I inject IRepository like this:

```
private readonly IRepository _repository;
public Service(IRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
}
```

Now I want to use my ModelData in ViewModel. GetAll should comes from Service but the rest of methods should comes from Repository and I see 2 options to do that:

1. I can inject into ViewModel IService for GetAll method and IRepository for rest of CRUD.
2. Inject IService into ViewModel only and implement in Service some kind of transparent methods like that:

   ```
   public void Add(ModelData Model)
   {
       _repository.Add(Model);
   }

   public void Edit(ModelData Model)
   {
       _repository.Edit(Model);
   }

   public void Remove(int id)
   {
       _repository.Remove(id);
   }
   ```

Which one method is better or maybe there is some other way to achieve my goals in better way?

Comment: They're all pretty complex.  If you're using something like Entity Framework, it already implements the Repository pattern, so layers for the sake of layers isn't needed. If your service layer is truly separate from your presentation layer (and is not just a pass through), then it's worth exploring how the service domain is different, and what those services decompose into.  Typically in an advanced situation there's some sort of automapping happening between repository DTOs and the presentation ViewModel (see Automapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is clearly better

> I can inject into ViewModel IService for GetAll method and IRepository
>   for rest of CRUD.

1. In this way your view model will depend on IService and IRepository. Both are abstractions that your view model depends on. So your view model is not dependent on details such as MSSQL implementation. Considering the MVVM architectural pattern, IService and IRepository both will belong to the model, and it is okay for the view model to depend on them.
2. If you had a transparent methods in your service, for every change in method in repository, you have to modify IRepository, IService and Service. This will reduce your efficiency of development.

On a side note, I would prefer to move the IRepository  from DataAccess  to DomainLogic. When done this way, the domain will not depend on data access but the data access will depend on domain.